# Starts with skating through a frozen city

Tags: story-identification

That is about all! I think early 90’s & Dan Simmons like?.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is _really_ light on details.  Can you at least narrow it down to whether it's a short story or a novel?  What about the story makes you say it's Simmons-like?  Why is the city frozen; is it just winter, or is it a post-apocalyptic scenario or a future ice age?  Who is skating; is it just one person or a group?  Why are they skating; are they trying to get somewhere or are they being pursued?  Are they skating on a frozen canal/river or are the streets full of ice?  Maybe there was just a bad ice storm and everyone's still indoors?

Comment: Please see our [checklist for asking a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and make sure it is [on-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (i.e. about science fiction or fantasy).

Comment: Frozen like ice? Unmoving? Time stopped? How like Dan Simmons? Ice skating? Roller skating?

Comment: Neverness... by David Zindell - almost certainly

Comment: I don't know Neverness, but on a quick look it would seem to fit. I don't recall it being a common opening for novels, so while the question is short I disagree with closing it immediately - voted to reopen.

Comment: I second Alith's suggestion. The opening chapter for Neverness is very memorable and if one never finished the next few chapters it's reasonable that that's the only thing one would remember of it.

Answer (score 6):

The immediate book that sprang to mind on the limited details in the OP was [*Neverness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverness) by David Zindell.

[image: Cover of "Neverness" showing a view of an icy path through a city of circular towers leading toward a snowy mountain in the distance. The view is framed by an arched portal, surrounding which is a starfield.]

Despite not having read the book for over 20 years (*Neverness* was first published back in 1988 (fitting into the time frame given of early 1990's), the memory of the protagonist (Mallory Ringess) skating through the ice covered streets in the first chapter has always stuck with me.

It would also I think be valid to compare David Zindell with Dan Simmons, *Neverness* is a dense, complicated work that bears some semblance to *Hyperion* (imho).

I've managed to dig out a PDF of the first few pages and have extracted them below to hopefully give OP something that meets with his memories...

If OP can find an online PDF copy the skating takes place in the first few pages and on...

> "I reached for my skates and pushed my feet into them.  They were cold and stiff from lying beneath the drafty window too long.....I put on my racing gloves and clipped in the blades of my skates.  I walked towards the heavy mahogany door of our room.  The long racing blades left dents in the alien woven Fravashi carpet.  Bardo bellowed as he stood up and followed behind me, smoothing out the dents with the balls of his black slippered feet. [...]
>
> We sped between Resa's Morning Towers tucked low and tight with our arms swinging and our skates clacking mechanically against the smooth red ice.  The cold wind against my face felt good.  In no time at all we shot past the  granite and basalt towers of the high professionals' college, Upplysa, and passed through the marble pillars of the west gate of the Academy, and there she was.
>
> She shimmers, my city. she shimmers.  She is said to be the most beautiful of all the cities of the Civilized Worlds, more beautiful even than Parpallaix or the cathedral cities of Vesper....

The above is Mallory and his friend Bardo emerging from their quarters into the titular city of Neverness and Mallory skating to meet with the recently returned Lord Pilot who returns after some 25 years of voyaging to Neverness during the time of false Winter.